# Unity3D Google admob: User is reward twice (or more) hack

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I created a daily reward system in which the player can get about three 500 coins a day, e.g. 1/3 gold coins. I use [Admob Unity Plugin](https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob) to show the player rewarded videos when they click on the button to get the 500 gold coins, the button can be clicked 3 times and each time the player watches a reward video, they get 500 gold coins.

My issue:

1: If the user clicks on the reward button and watch the reward video fully for the first time, my int will increase to 1 and player is rewarded 500 coins - (so it is, 1/3 with 500 coins)

2: if the user clicks on the reward button a second time but then decides to close the reward video, the int will **not** increase and the player is **not** rewarded 500 coins - (it is still, 1/3 with 500 coins)

3: But if the user decides to click on the reward button and then decided to watch the new reward video fully, the int will increase by **2** (instead of 1) and the player is now rewarded **1,000 gold coins** (instead of 500) - (it is now, 3/3 with 1,500 gold coins)

NOTE: this order isn't specific, the user could do this method from the start or before the int reaches 3/3 and do it however many times the user wants, simply by closing the reward video a lot of time (not completing the video) until satisfied and then watching the reward video fully 3 times.

I won't include my daily reward script, as I don't believe it is causing my issue.
Please could someone help me with this, thank you!!!!

This is my reward script:

````
    {
        public Admob ad;
        public int clickInt = 0;
        public Text clickText;
        public Image coinImage;
        public Button rewardButton;


    void Awake()
    {
            if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("amount"))
            {
                clickInt = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("amount");
            }
     }


      void Start ()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    Debug.Log("Unable to play ad in the EDITOR");
       if (clickInt == 1) { 
            clickText.text = "1/3 Daily uses"; 
       } else if (clickInt == 2) { 
            clickText.text = "2/3 Daily uses"; 
       } else if (clickInt >= 3) {
            clickInt = 3;
       }

       if (clickInt == 3) {
           clickText.text = "3/3 Daily uses";
       }
#elif UNITY_ANDROID

       if (clickInt == 1) { 
           clickText.text = "1/3 Daily uses"; 
       } else if (clickInt == 2) { 
           clickText.text = "2/3 Daily uses"; 
       } else if (clickInt >= 3) {
           clickInt = 3;
       }

       if (clickInt == 3) {
           clickText.text = "3/3 Daily uses";
       }     
#endif
      }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    Debug.Log("Unable to play ad in the EDITOR");
       if (clickInt == 1) { 
            clickText.text = "1/3 Daily uses"; 
       } else if (clickInt == 2) { 
            clickText.text = "2/3 Daily uses"; 
       } else if (clickInt >= 3) {
            clickInt = 3;
       }

       if (clickInt == 3) {
           clickText.text = "3/3 Daily uses";
       }
#elif UNITY_ANDROID

        ad = Admob.Instance ();
       if (ad.isRewardedVideoReady ()) {
          coinImage.enabled = true;
       } else {
          ad.loadRewardedVideo ("ca-app-pub-…………………/……………"); 
          coinImage.enabled = false;
       }

       if (clickInt == 1) { 
           clickText.text = "1/3 Daily uses";
           rewardButton.interactable = true; 
       } else if (clickInt == 2) { 
           clickText.text = "2/3 Daily uses";
           rewardButton.interactable = true;  
       } else if (clickInt >= 3) {
           clickInt = 3;
       }

       if (clickInt == 3) {
           clickText.text = "3/3 Daily uses";
           rewardButton.interactable = false; 
       }     
#endif
      }




       public void Free_500_Coins()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        Debug.Log("Unable to play ad in the EDITOR");
         clickInt += 1;
        ShopManager.Playercurrency += 500;
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        if (ad.isRewardedVideoReady ()) {
            Admob.Instance().interstitalRewardHandler += onInterstitalRewardVideoEvent;
            coinImage.enabled = true;
        ad.showRewardedVideo ();
    } else {
            ad.loadRewardedVideo ("ca-app-pub-............/..........."); 
            coinImage.enabled = false;
        }
#endif
    }


    void onInterstitalRewardVideoEvent(string eventNames, string msgs)
    {
        if (eventNames == "onRewarded")
        {
                Admob.Instance().interstitalRewardHandler -= onInterstitalRewardVideoEvent;
                Debug.Log("Well Done! You got 500 coins");
                clickInt += 1;
                ShopManager.Playercurrency += 500;
                Debug.Log("handler AdmobEventsHandler---" + eventNames + "   " + msgs);
        }
     }

    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        Admob.Instance().interstitalRewardHandler -= onInterstitalRewardVideoEvent;
    }

   }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove "onInterstitalRewardVideoEvent" from all of the assignments with + & - and add below these lines.

```
 void OnEnable() {
    Admob.Instance().interstitalRewardHandler += onInterstitalRewardVideoEvent;
}
void OnDisable() {
    Admob.Instance().interstitalRewardHandler -= onInterstitalRewardVideoEvent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this help. I came across a problem before which someone said I had to do this but I guess it didn't help! but thank you again, it really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `if (ad.isRewardedVideoReady ()) {` to `if (ad.isRewardedVideoReady () && !coinImage.enabled) {`.

Spamming the button that calls `Free_500_Coins` will cause two calls to adding the handler.

Comment: I'm not spamming the button that calls free_500_coins as I only press the button once. The button is never turned off, it is only ever interactable - true or false. the coin image is something else i want to turn on and off